# Составление алгоритм для выбора объектов из массива с суммарным весом равным 100

Tags: java, алгоритм

Есть задача:

> Напишите программу, вводящую последовательность целых чисел, которая считает их массами имеющихся в наличии предметов и выясняет, можно ли выбрать из них какое-то количество предметов с суммарным весом 100.

Моя идея решения алгоритмы, заключается в том чтобы суммировать вес всех объектов в последовательности и проверить, что их сумма не меньше 100. Таким образом, думаю, отсечь полноценное выполнение всего алгоритма до начала его выполнения.

Но дальше даже не пойму, так-как очень много итераций по последовательности сделать не вариант, а других вариантов не вижу.

Заранее спасибо за советы и ваши мысли.

Comment: Ну классическая задача о рюкзаке. Или об одномерном раскрое. Или... да много вариантов. И решения стандартны - ветви и границы, динамика, поиск в ширину и т.п. "Всё украдено ещё до Вас...".

Comment: @Akina, спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: О! кстати... надо вариант набора, или просто выяснить, можно или нельзя?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Заведите массив длиной 101. Заполните нулями, только поставьте единицу в A[0].

Теперь для каждого веса P пробегите по массиву
**уточнение**: в обратном направлении, чтобы не было ложных срабатываний от только что поставленных единиц.

Если в i-м элементе стоит 1, то сумму весов i можно собрать из предыдущих элементов, а значит, вместе с текущим можно собрать i+P, так что поставьте 1 в A[i+P].

Так делать, пока не кончатся элементы или не попадём в сотую ячейку массива.

Comment: Большое спасибо, за Вашу подсказку.

Answer (score 0):

Ест вариант решения:

1 - отсортировать массив, чтоби было по возрастанию числа.
2 - убираем числа, которие превышают 100 (1,2,45,87,110,205,304) - после отбора чисел - (1,2,45,87)
3 - Используем двоичную систему для "взятия числа из массива".

**Пример:**

Массив а = {4,25,36,60,75}

Началное двоичное число будет- *00001*
Конечное двоичное число будет- *11111*

После прибавляем в двоичной системе счисления единицу и считаем сумму на выпавшие ячейки единицы.

Если число, допустим, 11001, то берутся числа {`4`,`25`,36,60,`75`} и суммируются.

Для нашего примера сумма чисел = 100 будут:
10110 - {`4`,25,`36`,`60`,75}
01001 - {4,`25`,36,60,`75`}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]